# Webpage contained within one dynamic page, unable to use driver interactions with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, testing

The homepage for the web application I'm testing has a loading screen when you first load it, then a username/password box appears.  It is a dynamically generated UI element and the cursor defaults to being inside the username field.

I looked around and someone suggested using action chains.  When I use action chains, I can immediately input text into the username and password fields and then press enter and the next page loads fine.  Unfortunately, action chains are not a viable long-term answer for me due to my particular setup.

When I use the webdriver's `find_element_by_id` I am able to locate it and I am not able to `send_keys` to the element though because it is somehow not visible.  I receive

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible.

I'm also not able to click the field or otherwise interact with it without getting this error.

I have also tried identifying and interacting with the elements via other means, such as "xpaths" and css, to no avail.  They are always `not visible`.

Strangely, it works with dynamic page titles.  When the page first loads it is `Loading...` and when finished it is `Login`.  The driver will return the current title when `driver.title` is called.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Ok confirm me is there loading progress bar appears on login page when you are going to find element???

Comment: Yes, it is there.  I put a time.sleep(20) before trying to interact with it which is ample time for the login box to appear.

Comment: actually presence_of_element_located of element just checking element present on the DOM or not while visibility_of_element_located checking present and visible both, means presence_of_element_located also able to find hidden element as well as visible element while visibility gets only visible that's why presence_of_element_located works.

Comment: Now problem during send_keys, because selenium can not be intract to element until it's not visible that's why you are in trouble may be there are some hidden CSS works on desire element which makes it invisible that's why selenium unable to interact with it but don't worry you are still able to set value using execute_script.

Comment: Now you can try to set value on input element instead of using send_keys after element. Try with second updated answer and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if there is loading progress bar appears in you login page, You should try using [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait until element is getting visible as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "enter element id here")))

# now use send_keys
element.send_keys("enter value here")
```

**Edited1** :- If you're getting `TimeoutException`, I would suggest you try to wait before finding element to to be invisible loading progress bar using `WebDriverWait` instead of hard coded sleep wait then find desire element as below :-

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "enter loading progress bar  id or other locators here")))

#now after invisible of loading progress bar wait for desire element 
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "enter element id here")))

# now use send_keys
element.send_keys("enter value here")
```

**Edited2** :- actually `presence_of_element_located` of element just checking element present on the DOM or not while `visibility_of_element_located` checking present and visible both, means `presence_of_element_located` also able to find hidden element as well as visible element while visibility gets only visible that's why `presence_of_element_located` works.

Now problem during `send_keys`, because selenium can not be intract to element until it's not visible that's why you are in trouble may be there are some hidden `CSS` works on desire element which makes it invisible that's why selenium unable to interact with it but don't worry you are still able to set value using `execute_script`.

Now you can try to set value on input element instead of using `send_keys` after element finding as :-

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", element, "enter your value here")
```

Comment: I use a hard-coded wait to ensure the element is on screen, then did what you suggested.  The element is clearly visible on the screen and in the source but I still get a TimeoutException raised by the wait.until()  I tried switching frames, thinking it could be something wonky like that, but did not help.  Is there some sort of refresh I need to do for selenium to register the new source or something?

Comment: Ok then instead of hard coded wait use WebDriverWait to wait until loading bar invisible then find element, try edited answer and let me know...:)

Comment: I tried doing that.  It can find the loading bar just fine, and notices when it goes invisible, but still incapable of locating the username and password fields.  I'm considering just using action chains for this part and trying to automate other parts of the site to see if this will be a problem I encounter everywhere.

Comment: What error this time?? And could you tell me which locator are you using to locate input element?? And make sure your locator is correct and locate to correct element as well..:)

Comment: I use `wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[contains(.,'Loading application')]")))` to find the loading bar, which works.  I use `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'uname')))` to find the username field, which doesn't.  The error is `TimeoutException`, so it is looking for it for 10 seconds, fails, the throws the error.

Comment: Try using `presence_of_element_located` instead of `visibility_of_element_located` see the edited answer carefully..:)

Comment: And make sure there is only one element by I'd `uname`..to verify just goto browser console by pressing f12 at that page and execute this `$x("//*[@id ='uname']")` and let me know the result

Comment: It works!  Thank you so much!  I don't understand what the technical difference between `visibility` and `presence` is.  According to the documentation, `visibility` is on the DOM and has height/width, while `presence` just checks to see if it is on the DOM and doesn't care about visibility.  Do you know why `visibility` didn't work?

Comment: There is only one element that has the ID of 'uname'.

Comment: Now, I have a function that waits for the page load.  I'm still not able to send the element any keys because it is not visible...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121664/discussion-between-john-rodgers-and-saurabh-gaur).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by saurabh , use 
1 self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, OR.Sub_categories)))

Else put a sleep and see however it is not advisable to use that, may be the xpath you have changes at the time of page load

Comment: I tried both, including using an explicit wait until I know for sure the element was on the screen and then trying to locate it with a EC.visibility function.  It still can't locate the box.